# Django display function as list in html with template tags

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset, templatetags

Given my two models, Deck and Flashcard:

```
class Deck(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Flashcard(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
question = models.TextField()
answer = models.TextField()
```

I want to show the details of a particular deck, e.g. list of questions and answers for that deck.

So in my Deck model, I've got the following function:

```
def list_flashcards(self):
    fc_list = Flashcard.objects.filter(deck=self).values_list('question', flat=True)
    return fc_list
```

Now in my html template, if I use:

```
{{deck.list_flashcards}}
```

I get: `<QuerySet ['first', 'second','third']`

In other words, I get the right items, just not in the right format. How can I get this as a 'normal' list?

For example, when I use...

```
{{deck.list_flashcards.0}} <br>
{{deck.list_flashcards.1}} <br>
```

...it works. But I won't know how many cards a user will have, and also it's of course not efficient.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
{% for fc in fc_list %}
  Question: {{fc}}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work - nothing appears on the website.

Should I be adding this to my view for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are soooo close!

```
{% for card in deck.list_flashcards %}
  Question: {{card}}
{% endfor %}
```